# No keyboard events on iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, keyboard-events

I need to handle the keyboard events for my app, my code samples below are working on the Web and Android but not iOS.

I tried using RawKeyboard and the FocusNode but none of these methods are working on iOS.

Using RawKeyboard:

```
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    RawKeyboard.instance.addListener(_onKeyEvent);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: TextFormField()),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    RawKeyboard.instance.removeListener(_onKeyEvent);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onKeyEvent(RawKeyEvent value) {
    print('event: $value');
  }
}
```

Using the FocusNode:

```
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  late final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode(
    onKey: _onKey,
    onKeyEvent: _onKeyEvent,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: TextFormField(focusNode: _focusNode)),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  KeyEventResult _onKey(FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
    print('onKey: $event');
    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  }

  KeyEventResult _onKeyEvent(FocusNode node, KeyEvent event) {
    print('onKeyEvent: $event');
    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  }
}
```

Here is the output of flutter doctor:

```
% flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale en-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't know Flutter. But iOS doesn't have "keyboard events" so it seems likely that this would do nothing on iOS platform. — I notice that this was a known issue for a long time: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31945. Sorry not to be more help, just commenting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, since iOS 13.4 there is a way to handle the events and some changes have been made on Flutter too: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/65193
Maybe I'am missing something ?

Comment: Like I say, I'm not a Flutter person. But wouldn't that sort of event be purely an iPad thing? I wouldn't expect it to work on iPhone. Of course I could be wrong.